# Eloquent - Search ID in column like ['4','6','8'] (PHP Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I'm lost... I can't fetch my datas inside database...

So I have a table with name : preparation and with fields

ID, ..., ..., participants,.., ... .

I store IDs of another table in participants field with json_encode function like this : ['4','6','8'].

I would like to retrieve all results with an ID given. So for example if I had :

```
ID---name---participants--------otherfield
1---Step1---['6','8']-----------lorem1
2---Step2---['4','7','8']-------lorem2
3---Step3---['2','3','6','9']---lorem3
```

I would like to retrieve all lines with the number 6 so line 1 and 3.
I did several tests with eloquent, or querybuilder but without result.
For example I tried this :

```
$idToFind = 6;
$query = PreparationStep::
      whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(participants, ".$idToFind.")")
    ->get();
```

Please help me.

Comment: What exact string have for step 1st?

Comment: you should really have a `step_participants` table for a many-to-many relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Could you post the output of `PreparationStep::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(participants, ".$idToFind.")")->toSql()`?

Comment: Paras, 
This is the output : 
     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION laravel-role.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist (SQL: select * from `preparation_steps` where JSON_CONTAINS(participants, 4))

Comment: user2486, 
$idToFind is an integer

Comment: upgrade your mysql version

Comment: this is not json ['6','8']

Comment: Chay22, I can't upgrade my Mysql on my web host...

Comment: Have you checked this:
https://medium.com/@thakuramit3/laravel-provides-an-efficient-way-to-handle-json-column-in-the-table-with-its-magical-tool-a957c13004bf

This might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! Since `JSON_CONTAINS` returns 1 if it finds a match and 0 if not, you have to change your `whereRaw` statement like this (parameterize your raw statements to prevent sql injections)

```
$idToFind = 6; 
$query = PreparationStep::whereRaw("JSON_CONTAINS(participants, ?) = 1", [$idToFind])->get();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work
I think I need Mysql 5.7 to use JSON_CONTAINS, but I can't upgrade my MySQL version.

    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION laravel-role.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist (SQL: select * from `preparation_steps` where JSON_CONTAINS(participants, 6) = 1)

There are another way to do this ?

Comment: If you cant use the method, I guess you dont have any other choice but to use `LIKE`.

`where("participants", "like", "%\"{$idToFind}\"%")`

Comment: It was very simple... Thank you PaulSantos

Comment: I had to write my parameter as a string : '['.$idToFind.']' to make it work.

Comment: @yagrasdemonde did you just accepted an answer, even though it wasn't acceptable for you? o0

Answer (score 3):

[image]

here is my json column in subject table

```
foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
$arr[]="$value->id";
```

}
 $arr=json_encode($arr);// make dynamic json array

$data=Subject::whereRaw('json_contains(course_id, \''.$arr.'\')')->get();